# Understanding of Delete operator in JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var trees = ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple"];
delete trees[3];

if (3 in trees) {
  console.log(trees[3]);
}
else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

The answer shows "not found" but does not display undefined. Why is that? And even at the end, when we count the length of that array it shows, 5 and not 4. Why is that? Please explain with examples.

Comment: _The answer shows "not found" and not undefined_ that is because you are doing `console.log("not found");`

Comment: When we remove the else statement, it shows nothing in the console log

Comment: 1st of all, you have a typo: `tress` =/= `trees` I don't know if that is important in your actual code but check it (seems like it was important. Check mistakes like that before please)

Answer (score 1):

> The answer shows "not found" but does not display undefined. Why is that?

You deleted the property named `3` (this is not the same as the property existing but having the value `undefined`). Since it does not exist, it is not `in` the array. So you hit the `else` branch.

> And even at the end, when we count the length of that array it shows, 5 and not 4

The length is the name of the highest property that is named after an integer, plus one.

Comment: I understand this part, but when you remove the else statement, why does the console log not show anything at all? It does not even show undefined.

Comment: @Divij `if (3 in trees)` is always false  thats why . you have to use indexOf("oak") to check the element exists or not

Comment: @Divij — You are saying `if (false) { x } else { y }`. So it does `y`. If you remove the else, that doesn't make the `if` true. It just doesn't do what it did before, so it now does nothing.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. My bad, I didn't know something will show blank if its false. Thank you very much for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Added comments to your code for a better explanation

```js
let tress = ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple"];

// an array is an object with properties as index of the elements
// this prints all the keys currently in the object
console.log(Object.keys(tress));
delete tress[3];

console.log(tress);
// Now You can see that the property 3 has been removed from the array

console.log(Object.keys(tress));
if (3 in tress) {
    console.log(tress[3]);
}
else {
console.log("not found");
}

// Since the the property does not exist hence it prints not found
```

The [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator returns true if the specified property or list of properties is in the specified object. Since You removed that property you would get false

Comment: "an array can be treated as an object" — An array **is** an object.

Comment: that is what I meant

Comment: I want you to remove the else statement and see what is the answer then. For me it shows nothing in the console log and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: are you printing something specific ? If not you won't get any message since it does not go inside the else

Comment: Why will it show blank is my question and why not undefined?

Comment: console.log(trees[3]); would print undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. You declared

> var tress

And then you tried to delete non existing variable:

> delete trees[3]

The deletion command will remove an entry from the array, and make it undefined.

More details regarding delete can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 0):

The below code returns "not found" because "oak" has been deleted from the array.

```js
var trees = ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple"];
delete trees[3];
if (trees.indexOf("oak") > 0){
    console.log(trees[3]);
}
else {
console.log("not found");
}
```

Comment: @Divij which one ?

Comment: @Divij `indexOf" returns `-1` if the element is not found in the array.